# How can i GetRawInputDeviceInfo from Global Hook (WH_GETMESSAGE)

Tags: c++, dll, hook, hid, raw-input

I'm not sure i can do this.I am not familiar with window programming.I want to distinguish which device is coming from in these mouse or touch messages.The following code is in a DLL,which is a DLL file for hook.

```
MSG* pMsg = (MSG*)lparam;

    if (msg != 0 && msg2 != 0 && pMsg->message != msg && pMsg->message != msg2 )
    {
        if (pMsg->message == WM_TOUCH || (pMsg->message >= WM_MOUSEFIRST && pMsg->message <= WM_MOUSELAST )) {
            SendNotifyMessage(dstWnd, msg, (WPARAM)pMsg->hwnd, pMsg->message);
            SendNotifyMessage(dstWnd, msg2, pMsg->wParam, pMsg->lParam);
            //if(callBackFunc != NULL) callBackFunc("Hook Message: ");
            if (pMsg->message == WM_TOUCH) {
                if (callBackFunc != NULL) callBackFunc("Hook Message: WM_LBUTTONDOWN");
                translate(wparam,lparam);
                //pMsg->message = WM_NULL;
            }
        }
    }

void translate(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    UINT rawDatasSize(0);
    GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, NULL, &rawDatasSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

    vector<BYTE> buffer;
    buffer.resize(32);
    DWORD err1 = GetLastError();

    PRAWINPUT pRawInput = (PRAWINPUT) & (buffer[0]);
    GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, pRawInput, &rawDatasSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));

    RID_DEVICE_INFO deviceInfo;
    deviceInfo.cbSize = sizeof(RID_DEVICE_INFO);
    UINT infoSize = deviceInfo.cbSize;
    UINT result = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(pRawInput->header.hDevice, RIDI_DEVICEINFO, (LPVOID)&deviceInfo, &infoSize);
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    if (pRawInput->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEHID)
    {

        unsigned long long  version = (unsigned long long)deviceInfo.hid.dwVersionNumber;
        unsigned long long  vid = (unsigned long long)deviceInfo.hid.dwVendorId;
        unsigned long long  pid = (unsigned long long)deviceInfo.hid.dwProductId;
        cout<< "version: " << version << endl;
        cout<< "vid: " << vid << endl;
        cout<< "pid: " << pid << endl;
        //unsigned long long    deviceId = (version << 32) | (vid << 16) | pid;
    }

}
```

rawDatasSize is Always 0. err is always 6. So where I am wrong?